# Porque esta imagen no queda responsive?

Tags: html, css

Que esta mal en este css?

```css
.img-responsive{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
}

.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div className="hovereffect">
        <img className="img-responsive" src={imgdir + item.img} alt={item.name}/>
            <div className="overlay">
                <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                <p> 
                    <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</b>
                </p> 
                <p> 
                    <a href="#">VIEW DEMO</a>
                </p> 
            </div>
    </div>
```

Necesito que la imagen sea realmente responsive y no lo es, por ejemplo como mostrare a continuacion si pongo una imagen mas chica que la azul, (la azul es la que anda bien y tiene un tamaño de 1100 x 620) se ve asi digamos queda mas grande que las.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo con una imagen de internet? Tu ejemplo ahora mismo no se puede reproducir.

Comment: Intenta agregar: [`img {max-width: 100%;}`](http://jsbin.com/suzequ/edit?html,css,output) a tu css

Comment: No funciona agregando  img {max-width: 100%;}

Answer (score 1):

¿Has probado lo siguiente?

```
.img-responsive{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Con esto la imagen debería adaptarse en todo momento a su contenedor.